# MS Sql Server backup procedure not working in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup

I followed the instructions given on the following page and created a procedure to backup my ms sql DB : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019698

Then I executed it to test it, and it worked perfectly. So I decided I would now execute this procedure from my C# application. I used the same structure that I use to open a connection and execute my other commands to execute this new one, and I provide the procedure with the following parameters :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@databaseName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = DBName;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@backupType", SqlDbType.Char, 1).Value = BackupType;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@backupLocation", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = BackupType;
```

When I run the program it executes without any errors however when I navigate to the destination folder there is no backup BAK file to be found. It is there when I execute the procedure from management studio but when I delete the BAK file and try to run the procedure from my C# application it does not create the BAK file. The databaseName parameter is sysname in management studio and narchar in C# as the sqldbType, can that be a problem?

Comment: You set the @backupLocation to BackupType. Could that be the problem or is it just a mistake in the question?

Comment: Oh my goodness, that is the problem. Thank you.